# Использование list вместо tuple в init модулей

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuple

Во многих крупных проектах, даже в таких как [django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/__init__.py), и в [официальной документации к python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id24) используют `list` для перечисления доступных "извне" компонентов модуля в файле __init __.py:

```
__all__ = [foo, bar, other]
```

Тем не менее, запись

```
__all__ = (foo, bar, other)
```

тоже будет работать и, в теории, даёт не значительное увеличение производительности кода.

Почему тогда используют именно `list`?
Может есть какой то магический PEP, о котором я не знаю?

Comment: `(foo, bar, other)` - это не `set`, это `tuple`, а `set` выглядел бы так: `{foo, bar, other}`

Comment: может потому, что кортеж - неизменяем?

Comment: @Jack_oS а зачем изменять кортеж во вне?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__all__` делают списком, потому что так указано в официальной документации Python: PEP8 также называет `__all__` списком.

Вспомогательные инструменты могут полагаться на это соглашение и подсвечивать код как неверный с точки зрения PEP257.

Инициализация `__all__` **как кортежа** не решает проблему экономии. Так как разрешение импортов оптимизировано в самом интерпретаторе.

Инициализация `__all__` **как множества** может быть избыточным (особенно если значений немного/несколько), так как в основе множества лежит структура хэш-таблица.

Comment: Напрашивается другой вопрос: почему PEP8 называет `__all__` списком?